# Eval madness in ksh

Tags: eval, ksh

Man I hate `eval`...

I'm stuck with this ksh, and it *has* to be this way.

There's this function I need, which will receive a variable name and a value. Will do some things to the contents of that variable and the value and then would have to update the variable that was received. Sort of:

```
REPORT="a text where TADA is wrong.."

setOutputReport REPORT "this"

echo $REPORT
a text where this is wrong..
```

Where the function would be something like

```
function setOutputReport {
    eval local currentReport=\$$1
    local reportVar=$1
    local varValue=$2

    newReport=$(echo "$currentReport"|sed -e 's/TADA/$varValue')

    # here be dragons
    eval "$reportVar=\"$newReport\""
}
```

I had this headache before, never manage to get this eval right at first. Important here, the `REPORT` var may contain multiple lines (`\n`'s). This might be important as one of the attempts managed to correctly replace the contents of the variable with the fist line only :/

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One risk, not with eval but with the "varValue" as the replacement in the sed command: if varValue contains a slash, the sed command will break

```
local varValue=$(printf "%s\n" "$2" | sed 's:/:\\/:g')
local newReport=$(echo "$currentReport"|sed -e "s/TADA/$varValue/")
```

If your printf has the %q specifier, that will add a layer of security -- %q escapes things like quotes, backticks and dollar signs, and also escaped chars like newline and tab:

```
eval "$(printf "%s=%q" "$reportVar" "$newReport")"
```

Here's an example of what %q does (this is bash, I hope your version of ksh corresponds):

```
$ y='a `string` "with $quotes"
with multiple
lines'
$ printf "%s=%q\n" x "$y"
x=$'a `string` "with $quotes"\nand multiple\nlines'
$ eval "$(printf "%s=%q" x "$y")"
$ echo "$x"
a `string` "with $quotes"
and multiple
lines
```